# How to append lines from file into a list while keeping the number of lines - python 3

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to stem words from a file that contains about 90000 lines (each line has three to several hundred words.
I want to append the lines to a list after stemming the words. I was able to insert the stemmed words into a list, which contains one line. I want to insert the words into the list while keeping the 90000 lines. Any ideas?

clean_sentence = []
    with open(folder_path+text_file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:

```
    for line in f:
        sentence = line.split()

        for word in sentence:
            if word.endswith('er'):
                clean_sentence.append(word[:-2])
            else:
                clean_sentence.append(word)
        x = ' '.join(clean_sentence)

    with open('StemmingOutFile.txt','w', encoding="utf8") as StemmingOutFile:
        StemmingOutFile.write(x)
```

The file is not in English, but here is an example that illustrates the issue at hand: current code yields:

```
why don't you like to watch TV? are there any more fruits? why not?
```

I want the output file to be:

```
why don't you like to watch TV?

are there any more fruits?

why not?
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Can you give a sample of your input file, the output you're currently getting, and the desired output? Off the bat, one guess is that you are overwriting your output file in each iteration. If that's the issue, try opening the file in append mode: `open('StemmingOutFile.txt','a', encoding="utf8") as StemmingOutFile:`. You may also need to add a newline.

Comment: please see the changes I've made in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Make the change to write in `append` mode (as shown in my first comment) and add a newline character when you write: `StemmingOutFile.write(x + "\n")`.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file in lines:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

and then do the stemming:

```
new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    new_lines.append(' '.join[stemmed(word) for word in line])
```

where `stemmed` is a function as follows:

```
def stemmed(word):
    return word[:-2] if word.endswith('er') else word
```

Then write each line of `new_lines` in *StemmingOutFile.txt*.